# How can we make an if statement work if condition = 0

Tags: javascript

`let chooseANumber = Number(prompt('Choose a number')); if (chooseANumber === 0) { console.log(0); }`
('Above the problem i am facing is if user closes the prompt window still 0 is logged into the console and if the user does not input anything still the Number(prompt) will change NaN into 0 and again 0 is logged. What can i do to change the condition to falsy if user does not input anything or closes the prompt window.');

I could not find any solution without changing first line.

Comment: [`prompt()` returns a string or `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#return_value). In case the user enters nothing, the result is `null`. [`null` is being coerced to `0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_coercion) by the `Number()` function. So everything working like expected.

Comment: So do not change it to a Number right away! `const resp = prompt()`; Check the value and then convert it to a number.

Comment: As @epascarello says: `let chooseANumber = prompt('Choose a number'); 
if(chooseANumber) chooseANumber = Number(chooseANumber)
if (chooseANumber===0) { console.log(0); }`

Comment: Why can you not change the first line? (At least, that's what the last line of your question implies.)

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert prompt return value to number immediately. When users closes prompt return value is NULL. But NULL is coerced to 0. Just check for NULL and then compare value as string or convert it to number if needed.

```
const v = prompt("Choose number");
if(v !== null) {
   //You can convert  v to number here if needed
   if(v === "0") console.log(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine

```js
const chooseNumberStr = prompt('Choose a number');
const chooseNumber = parseFloat(chooseNumberStr);
if (chooseNumber === 0) 
{ console.log(chooseNumber); }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.